# Is a soft SPF fail bad?

Tags: email, email-server, spf, email-bounces

Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning user@domain.com does not designate XXX.XX.XXX.XXX as permitted sender) client-ip=XXX.XX.XXX.XXX;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning user@domain.comdoes not designate XXX.XX.XXX.XXX as permitted sender) smtp.mail=user@domain.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are expecting your mail to be reliably delivered, then a soft fail is not good.  Your message may still be delivered depending on the policy of the receiving system.

For the best chance of successful delivery you should update your SPF record so the message you are trying to send is permitted.

Comment: Ideally "every server that can send mail for [domain]" will be listed in the SPF record.  If you can't enumerate that list you should tag your SPF record with `?all` to indicate that it is not an exhaustive list.